# Fetch initial data from server befor render in React + Redux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Load initial data from server to Redux store
I have a Redux store, with data, for example, shopping cart object with products. By default, I use an empty array

```
const initialState = {cart: {products: []}}
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) { return {...state} }
const store = createStore(reducer)
```

I need to load initial data from server and put into products array before app load instead of an empty array
I found two ways to implement this, but I doubt which one is better, or maybe no one

## 1 - INIT_APP Action

1. Create INIT_APP action and initApp() async action creator (using thunk fore example)
2. dispatch it on componentDidMount method in App.js component
3. Fetch data from the server inside initApp() and dispatch INIT_APP_SUCCESS action on success
4. Listen to INIT_APP_SUCCESS inside reducer and receive cart product data
5. Update store

---

```
const initialState = {cart: {products: []}}
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case: INIT_APP_SUCCESS
      return {...state, products: action.payload.cartProducts}
  }
}
```

## 2 - Async react dom

1. Fetch data from server inside index.js
2. On success call ReactDOM.render
3. Pass data into createStore preloadedState agrument as initial state

---

```
ReactDOM.render(<Loader />, ...)
axios.get(url).then(products => {
  const store = createStore(reducer, {cart: {products}})
  ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, ...)
}
```

Comment: You're on the right track with your first option.  If you're using `redux-thunk` you create an async action creator that handles the lifecycle of your request.  Then in your root react component you can subscribe to the store and only render the component that shows your product when the data is available.

Comment: Thanks for answer!
I also think the first option is more clear way, because I don't like to place initial state in createStore function, outside of reducer file. But in this approach INIT_APP seems like redundant action, which serves only for initial data fetching and hasn't triggered during application life. It doesn't looks like application state, which I change in runtime. That's why I have doubts about using it.